# How can I convert this XOR-encryption function from Delphi to C#?

Tags: c#, delphi, encryption

The following Delphi routine is originally from a long-ago CompuServe posting, and is used to encrypt various information in our database. Below are both the Delphi 2007 and (thanks to some SO help with the Unicode differences) Delphi XE versions.

We have been trying to convert this to C#, and have gotten close-ish, but we're missing something somewhere. Unfortunately, our Delphi guy (me) doesn't know C#, and the C# guy is new to Delphi. C# doesn't (appear to) have the concept of AnsiString, so the solution will probably involve byte or char arrays?

We'd greatly appreciate any help in converting this to C#.

Delphi 2007 Version (ASCII)

```
function EncodeDecode(Str: string): string;
const
  Hash: string = '^%12hDVjED1~~#29afdmSD`6ZvUY@hbkDBC3fn7Y7euF|R7934093*7a-|-  Q`';
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 1 to Length (Str) do
    Str[I] := chr (ord (Str[I]) xor not (ord (Hash[I mod Length (Hash) + 1])));
  Result := Str;
end;
```

Delphi XE Version (Unicode)

```
function TfrmMain.EncodeDecode(Str: AnsiString): AnsiString;
const
  Hash: string = '^%12hDVjED1~~#29afdmSD`6ZvUY@hbkDBC3fn7Y7euF|R7934093*7a-|-  Q`';
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := Str;
  for I := 1 to Length (Result) do
    Result[I] := AnsiChar (ord (Result[I]) xor not (Ord (Hash[I mod Length (Hash) + 1])));
end;
```

Comment: Just a note: Since now your encryption method including the key (this is your "Hash" string) is fully public, you should change this string as soon as possible, otherwise your data is not safe at all against attackers. But then you can switch to a better algorithm altogether.

Comment: Thanks Paŭlo - I mangled the key before posting here. Our actual key is much different.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know C# either, so this is probably seriously non-idiomatic.

```
static string EncodeDecode(string str)
{
    byte[] hash = new byte[63] { 94, 37, 49, 50, 104, 68, 86, 106, 69, 68, 49, 126, 
        126, 35, 50, 57, 97, 102, 100, 109, 83, 68, 96, 54, 90, 118, 85, 89, 64, 
        104, 98, 107, 68, 66, 67, 51, 102, 110, 55, 89, 55, 101, 117, 70, 124, 82, 
        55, 57, 51, 52, 48, 57, 51, 42, 55, 97, 45, 124, 45, 32, 32, 81, 96 };

    Encoding ANSI = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
    byte[] input = ANSI.GetBytes(str);
    byte[] output = new byte[input.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        output[i] = (byte)(input[i] ^ ~hash[(i + 1) % hash.Length]);
    return ANSI.GetString(output);
}
```

I have assumed that your ANSI strings are encoded with Windows 1252, but it you happen to have encoded your legacy data with a different code page it is obvious enough how to change it.

Since C# doesn't have the equivalent of Delphi's 8 bit string types, I personally would be sorely tempted to use `byte[]` rather than `string`.

Done that way it looks like this:

```
static byte[] EncodeDecode(byte[] input)
{
    byte[] hash = new byte[63] { 94, 37, 49, 50, 104, 68, 86, 106, 69, 68, 49, 126, 
        126, 35, 50, 57, 97, 102, 100, 109, 83, 68, 96, 54, 90, 118, 85, 89, 64, 
        104, 98, 107, 68, 66, 67, 51, 102, 110, 55, 89, 55, 101, 117, 70, 124, 82, 
        55, 57, 51, 52, 48, 57, 51, 42, 55, 97, 45, 124, 45, 32, 32, 81, 96 };

    byte[] output = new byte[input.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        output[i] = (byte)(input[i] ^ ~hash[(i + 1) % hash.Length]);
    return output;
}
```

@Groo makes the excellent point that the hash can be initialised more cleanly list this:

```
byte[] hash = ANSI.GetBytes(@"^%12hDVjED1~~#29afdmSD`6ZvUY@hbkDBC3fn7Y7euF|R7934093*7a-|-  Q`");
```

Comment: I believe `~hash[(i + 1 %...` should be just `~hash[i %...` because C# string indices are 0-based.

Comment: @John You believe wrong. The (i+1) is needed to match the Delphi version. Work it out.  In Delphi we have `I mod Length (Hash) + 1` which for `I=1`, the first time round the loop, gives a value of 2, the second character. Hence we need `(i+1) % length` in the C# to get at the second character (index 1) when `i=0`, first time round.

Comment: Non-idiomatic, perhaps. (Like I'd know). But I plugged the string version into the garbled mess I was working on in VS, and lo, it appears to work. Now to code the million random phrase test. Thanks very much!

Comment: @Eric, @David: my 2c would be to write something like `byte[] hash = yourEncoding.GetBytes(yourHashString);` somewhere outside the method (you don't want to repeat it on each call, but I don't even want to ask how David got these numbers from the initial post :-D).

Comment: @Groo I used a for loop in Delphi to get them but I agree that yourEncoding.GetBytes() is better.

Comment: @David & Groo, I mangled the hash string for posting here, so I had to figure out the proper array for our actual string. I just looked at the GExperts ASCII table tool. Tedious, and error prone. Which, incidentally, is how I've been described on occasion.

Comment: @David - bah, thanks for clearing that up. After a quick glance I wondered why it would start at character index 2 of the key and then commented a bit too soon, but I realize now that without the `+ 1` in there the `mod` operation would result in 0 if the message length were to grow to the size of the key.

Answer (score 2):

`String` in C# is a sequence of characters encoded in UTF-16, as explained in [this article by Jon Skeet](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/strings.html). That actually shouldn't concern you at all, until you decide to serialize it binary (i.e. convert it into a byte array). In that case, there is a class called [`Encoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86hf4sb8.aspx) in `System.Text` namespace which supports encoding the `String` to whatever encoding you want.

An `AnsiString` in Delphi is <strike>basically an ASCII string</strike> (nope, it's really an ANSI string, like the name says), where each character is guaranteed to have exactly 8 bits. This is a relatively "simple" encoding of encoding to work with, since it is of fixed size, widely accepted and compatible with legacy systems (but it doesn't allow encoding of more than 255 characters).

In other words, both of your versions deal with the same type of Encoding, but the unicode version now explicitly defines legacy strings as `AnsiString`s. That means that the latter version doesn't actually support Unicode strings, but the type needed to be changed with the new Delphi version.

What @David did while I was writing this lengthy nonsense is basically what I was going to write, with the exception that I would have used the [`Encoding.ASCII`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.ascii.aspx) encoding instead (**[edit] and would fail miserably due to the fact that ASCII only uses the lower 7-bits to encode characters, as mentioned by David below**). [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) is the encoding most commonly referred to as "ANSI" (although, if you check that Wiki article, you will find out that it, according to Microsoft, *The term ANSI as used to signify Windows code pages is a historical reference, but is nowadays a misnomer that continues to persist in the Windows community*).

Comment: Encoding.ASCII doesn't work. It's only 7 bits wide. You need an 8 bit encoding. Fair guess is that it is 1252.

Comment: @David: you are right. ASCII is a 7-bit character set. Delphi's AnsiString is an 8-bit set, I got it wrong.

Comment: Actually there are lots of 8 bit ANSI encodings, 1252 is the most widespread being English. Note that I am not approving of 1252's pre-eminence by making this statement!

Comment: @David: :) At the end it comes to checking the right encoding in the docs and using it. This data might easily use lowest 7-bits only (**the hash string does, for instance**). I just wanted to explain how encoding basically works in C#. The whole thing is one of notorious [humanity fails](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail.aspx).